# Wordpress NAV Walker not showing

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have custom theme for wordpress. but  i did not see the end_lvl function result in

```
class Walker_menu_footergo extends Walker_Nav_Menu { 
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output.= "<ul>";
  }

  function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output.= '<li><a href="javascript:;" data-target="#rgister-rooftop" data-toggle="modal" href="#rgister-rooftop" class="hvr-overline-from-center  menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom "><span>Register Your Rooftop</span></a></li></ul>';
  }
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    if ($depth == 0)
      $hvr_class = 'hvr-overline-from-center';
    else
      $hvr_class = '';
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $item ->classes)) {
      $output.= "<li ><a class='current '".implode(' ', $item ->classes)." ' href='".$item ->url."'><span>".esc_attr($item ->title).'</span></a>';
    } else {
      $output.= "<li ><a class='".$hvr_class.' '.implode(' ', $item ->classes)." ' href='".$item ->url."'><span>".esc_attr($item ->title).'</span></a>';

    }
  }
}
```

in the footer.php I have call this function

```
$footmenu=array('menu'=>'footer','menu_id'=>'','menu_class'=>'foot-menu','container'=>'ul','depth' => 0,'walker'  => new Walker_menu_footergo());

<?php echo wp_nav_menu($footmenu); ?>
```

it return all result except the end_lvl function

Comment: Is the closing `</ul>` there? (please look directly in the source code, not via DOM insprector)

Comment: yes there is closing tag <ul> in the end_lvl function.